# Why doesn't Xcode automatically add viewDidUnload for me?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm reading this text on iOS 5 development, and it says the following:

```
Delete all the methods except for viewDidUnload. When you’re finished,
your implementation should look like this:

#import "BIDViewController.h" @implementation BIDViewController
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view. // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
@end
```

Only, I never had that method. And it says it should automatically adds methods to that method when I link up actions and outlets, but since I had to add it randomly it doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this method is deprecated in iOS 6. [See the docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload)

Comment: This question have ios5 tag, i think it's matter

Comment: @NeverBe maybe yes. But here I doubt. Lot of iOS development questions misuse tags (see questions tagged with `Xcode` despite the question not making any difference if OP used nano and make to write his application...)

Comment: Most likely with Xcode 4.5 the template no longer includes viewDidUnload since it is deprecated. However, if the app will support iOS 4.3 or iOS 5.x then viewDidUnload should still be implemented when appropriate.

Comment: @rmaddy Absolutely right. But I was not saying it is not to be implemented. I just gave a reasoning why it is omitted from Xcode 4.5's (defaulting-to-iOS6) project templates.

Comment: @H2CO3, sorry, my comment was meant more for the OP and NeverBe. I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Per WWDC, it is recommended you not implement `viewDidUnload` on iOS 5. The reasoning is that much of the need for `viewDidUnload` was obviated by iOS devices having more memory, and iOS itself (IIRC) getting rid of the memory backing views. There's no harm, but Apple's analysis showed it led to many bugs and so wasn't worth while.

Answer (score 2):

this method is deprecated now

by the way, you don't have to do anything with IBOutlets if you don't have `strong` links to them

Comment: I make all my IBOutlet strong...is that bad? There's no circular reference...unless there's a delegate. So I should be nilling the delegate? WHAT HAVE I BEEN DOING??

Comment: relax, don't make IBOutlets and delegates `strong` and everything will be ok, you won't have to worry about nilling them =)